# Taking Current Location via Google Maps API

Tags: java, android

What I want to do is putting a mark on the current location of the user. I get an error like `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference`.
Why `getLatitude` method returns null and what can I do to fix that? Thanks for your help.
Here is my code:

```java
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public GoogleMap mMap;
    public Location location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera

        LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getAltitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("You are here"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLocation));
    }
}
```

Comment: location.getAltitude()

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize the location. That's why you get the null pointer exception. Use this code portion to initialize the location then add a marker.

```
private double longitude;
private double latitude;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //Initializing googleApiClient
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}
private void getCurrentLocation() {
        mMap.clear();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        if (location != null) {
            //Getting longitude and latitude
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();

            //moving the map to location
            moveMap();
        }
    }
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
   

     getCurrentLocation();
   }

 private void moveMap() {
        /**
         * Creating the latlng object to store lat, long coordinates
         * adding marker to map
         * move the camera with animation
         */
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .draggable(true)
                .title("Marker in My Location"));

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);


    }
```

Comment: I tried your code.
 'code'Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient); 
In this part there is a problem. It says create local variable googleApiClient or create field googleApiClient in MapsActivity.

Comment: Sorry I updated the answer. Initialize googleApiClient in onCreate()

Comment: About Google API Client it says uses or overrides a deprecated API. Instead of that it suggests fused location provider client. Do you have any idea about that? Sorry for taking your time.